# Adding a string to a CSV file while monitoring existing string combinations in the CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

I'm trying to write a C# method that will add a set of strings to a CSV file. It will be like this,

```
public void StoreWords(string expectedValue, stringActualValue)
{
  ///Store expectedValue, actualValue, and a seed value per row in the
  /// .csv file. If the combination of the expectValue and actualValue
  ///does not exist in the .csv file, then initialize a seed value for that 
  ///combination, otherwise increment the seed value for that combination
  }
```

I'm getting stuck on opening a csv file and storing the combination of words. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Question is too broad (there is more than one question...). Start by searching for "how to read a file in c#". Then search for "how to append to a file in c#". And maybe "how to parse a csv file in c#". Then try out what you learn, and come back with a specific question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I think that code should meet your requirements:

```
private string FilePath { get; set; }

private string[] ReadFile()
{
    return File.ReadAllLines(FilePath);
}

public Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, string> MakeOrIncSeedValuesFromCsv(string[] lines)
{
    var valuePairToSeedValue = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, string>();

    var lines = ReadFile();
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        var values = lines[i].Split(',');

        if (values.Length > 2)
        {
            var newSeedValue = IncSeedValue(lines[2]);
            var key = Tuple.Create<string, string>(values[0], values[1]);

            if (!valuePairToSeedValue.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                valuePairToSeedValue.Add(key, newSeedValue);
            }
            else
            {
                valuePairToSeedValue[key] = newSeedValue;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            var key = Tuple.Create<string, string>(values[0], values[1]);
            var seed = GetSeedValue(key);

            if (!valuePairToSeedValue.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                valuePairToSeedValue.Add(key, seed);
            }
            else
            {
                valuePairToSeedValue[key] = seed;
            }
        }
    }

    return valuePairToSeedValue;
}

private string GetSeedValue(Tuple<string, string> values)
{
    return // put your code here
}

private string IncSeedValue(string actualSeedValue)
{
    return // put your code here
}
```

}

Comment: There is a slight problem in the code when I try to use it. In the MakeOrIncSeedValuesFromCsv method parameters, you have string [] lines in there. But inside the method you have var lines. This is confusing to myself and the complier. In the for loop that declared, the limit that the loop is supposed to increment to is based on the line.Length. Which line are you referring to?

Comment: Also, I was able to implement IncSeedValue(string actualSeedValue). But I'm having an issue with private string GetSeedValue(Tuple<string, string> values).

Comment: Delete this argument from the method. Will be fine.